# return object in an array with the most props

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, higher-order-functions

Say I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arr = [
   { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
   { a: 1 },
   { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
   { a: 1, b: 2 }
];
```

How can I return the object with the most properties/keys? Preferably using in an efficient and terse manner using higher order functions.

Comment: does the properties have all the same values?

Comment: No the values are different so your second solution would be the most appropriate. Thanks Nina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign to a single object.

```js
const 
    array = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(object);
```

If you have different values, you could reduce the array.

```js
const 
    array = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }],
    object = array.reduce((a, b) => Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(b).length
        ? a
        : b
    );

console.log(object);
```

Comment: In the first solution from what does it know which object have the most keys?

Comment: @Alex, it assign simply all properties to the target object, whithout knowing the length. by having different values of same neamed properties, the last values win.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of keys from an object by calling `Object.keys(obj)` and then checking it's `length` property.
With that, you could reduce the array by checking each pair of objects and return the one with the most keys as a one liner:

```js
const biggestObject = 
    arr.reduce((a, b) => Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(b).length ? a : b);
```